# Redirect en gh-pages con react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, redirección, router, react-router-dom

Tengo un proyecto hecho con React y react-router dom para enlazar entre rutas en el siguiente [link de gh-pages](https://00frank.github.io/boxtree-reactjs/).

Al principio todo funciona bien, se puede navegar entre los distintos componentes e incluso entre las **secciones** dentro de ese componente identificadas con un **id** *(error que pude solucionar)*.

[image: Aplicación funcionando correctamente]

El problema viene cuando **recargo la página** en alguna de las secciones, seguido del link original, osea: `https://00frank.github.io/boxtree-reactjs/+componente`. Esto provoca que me direccione a un 404 Not Found.

[image: 404 Not Found]

Mi teoria es que al ser una [SPA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) espera que haya un index.html por cada `/sub-ruta` que tiene el proyecto, pero hay un único index.html que es el que recarga cada uno de los componentes.
Adjunto código de alguno de los componentes *(no creo que tenga mucho que ver con el código en si, si no con una implementación que hacer)*

---

## `<App/>`

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
//hago import de los componentes
//import { Header, Proyectos, InfoProyecto, FiltradorTabla } from *ruta de cada componente*

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/proyectos">
              <Proyectos />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/info-proyecto">
              <InfoProyecto />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/">
              <FiltradorTabla />
            </Route>
            {* puse esta ruta para decir que en caso de que no concuerde con niguno del Switch entre por                                     
             default al componente <FiltradorTabla /> pero se ve que no funciona *}
            <Route>
              <FiltradorTabla />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## `<Header/>`

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from '../../logo.svg';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Header.css'

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <header className="App-header">
        <div id="brand">
          <Link to="/">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1>BoxTree</h1>
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div id="sections">
          {SECTIONS.map(e => <Link to={e.href} key={e.name}>{e.name}</Link>)}
        </div>
      </header>
    )
  }
}

const SECTIONS = [
  { name: 'Productos', href: '/' },
  { name: 'Descuentos', href: '/' },
  { name: 'Información del proyecto', href: '/info-proyecto' },
  { name: 'Más proyectos', href: '/proyectos' }
]
```

---

Mi pregunta es si se puede crear un redireccionamiento cada vez que se recarga cualquier componente, para  que lo redireccione al mismo o, que al menos lo redireccione al inicio y no quede en la página de status 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución a mi problema, dejo la respuesta para alguno si en algún momento se encuentra como yo.
Como dice Tasio, el enrutamiento primero lo realiza el servidor, y como el proyecto esta subido a Github pages, no tengo acceso al mismo. Por lo que hay que hacer unos [pequeños trucos](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages#single-page-apps-for-github-pages) para hacer que se redireccione al index y que luego este maneje las rutas del front-end para usarlas con react-router-dom

## Solución

### (para gh-pages o hostings sin acceso a configuraciones del sv)

1. Crear un archivo 404.html con el [siguiente script](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages/blob/gh-pages/404.html) que redirija al index.html
2. Añadir el siguiente [script de redireccionamiento](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L36-L57) en el index.html, basicamente este checkea si hay una redireccion pendiente en la url y la añade al `browserHistory`

Dejo la fuente de [StackOverflow en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060999/15171741) donde encontré la solución

Answer (score 0):

Si, como dices es porque el servidor web por defecto va a buscar las rutas en carpetas y siempre debería ir al index.html

Para solucionar eso, depende el servidor donde se hostee, es de un modo u otro.

Con un apache que es lo más habitual, se puede solucionar con el archivo .htaccess

Haciendo la redirección así:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```